# Rails 3.1 - Editing Attributes in join models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm having real trouble getting my head around editing attributes in has_many through join models. I've set up a very simple app to experiment with; Recipes, Ingredients and Recipe_Ingredients (the join).

Can anyone help with making this work as it should? As it is, it'll pulling through 'qty' from the join model, but not the actual ingredient.

I've put a public repo up that anyone can download to play with: https://github.com/EssentialMusic/Recipes

The models:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name  
  has_many :recipe_ingredients, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recipes, :through => :recipe_ingredients
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author, :description, :name, :recipe_ingredients_attributes, :ingredients_attributes
  has_many :recipe_ingredients, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipe_ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => :true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
  attr_accessible :measure, :qty, :special_instructions
end
```

The form

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
  <% if @recipe.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@recipe.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this recipe from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :author %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :author %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

<div>
    <%= f.fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |ri| %>
    <%= ri.text_field :qty %> - 
        <%= ri.fields_for :ingredients do |i| %>
            <%= i.text_field :name %><br>
        <% end %>   
    <% end %>   
</div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the ri with f in the second nested fields_for like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |ri| %>
 <%= ri.text_field :qty %> -
      <%= **f**.fields_for :ingredients do |i| %>
         <%= i.text_field :name %><br>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That works fine if there's only one ingredient, but if there's more it seems to return extra results....if two ingredients, you'd get them both listed for each line....duplicated, so 2x2 if that makes any sense?